# How can I have the text inside the node aligned to the left (the black box-ish shape)?

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, nodes

I have run into a weird problem. For some reason, the text bits inside the node get pushed and pushed more to the right, the more I compile. If I activate the `overlay` option for my custom command, the vertical spacing is false which leads to another headache.

How can I have the text inside the node aligned to the left (the black box-ish shake)?

## Picture of Problem

[image]

## MWE

```
% !TeX spellcheck = en_Us

\documentclass[
a4paper,
DIV=15,
german,
%landscape,
%footheight=10pt,
fontsize=10pt,
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{
backgrounds,
positioning,
calc,
matrix
}

\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}

\newlength{\xdistance}
\setlength{\xdistance}{4pt}
\newlength{\yAbstand}
\setlength{\yAbstand}{10pt}

\newcommand{\specialsec}[1]{%
    %\raisebox{-0.2\height}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    remember picture=true,
%   overlay,
    ]
    \node[
%   xshift=-5pt,
    %draw=\specialsechintergrund,
    inner xsep=0pt,
    outer xsep=0pt,
    inner ysep=2pt,
    outer ysep=2pt,
    font=\LARGE\rmfamily,
    text=black,
    %text=white,
    align=left,
    anchor=south west,
    %   yshift=-1.0cm,
    %   minimum height=1.85cm,
    %xshift=2em,
    ]
    (AbschnittNode) {%
        #1%
    };%
    %### Nodes/Koordinaten für Abschnittsüberschrift setzen
    \draw[
    inner xsep=0pt,
    outer xsep=0pt,
    inner ysep=0pt,
    outer ysep=0pt,
    ]
    ($(AbschnittNode.west -| current page text area.west)+(\xdistance,\yAbstand)$) coordinate (AbschnittBoxRO)
    ($(AbschnittNode.west -| current page text area.west)+(\xdistance,-\yAbstand)$) coordinate (AbschnittBoxRU)
    ($(AbschnittNode.west -| current page text area.west)+(0pt,-\yAbstand)$) coordinate (AbschnittBoxLU)
    ($(AbschnittNode.west -| current page text area.west)+(0pt,\yAbstand)$) coordinate (AbschnittBoxLO)
    ;
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{foreground}
    \fill[
        inner sep=0pt,
        outer sep=0pt,
        fill=black,
    ]
    ($(AbschnittBoxLO -| current page text area.west)+(-\xdistance,0pt)$) rectangle ($(AbschnittBoxLU)+(0,-0.8pt)$);
    \end{pgfonlayer}
    \draw[
    ultra thick,
    black,
    ] ($(AbschnittBoxLU -| current page text area.west)+(0,0)$) -- ($(AbschnittBoxRU -| current page text area.east)+(0pt,0)$);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\listfiles

\begin{document}
Here are some words to form some random text.
1: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
2: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
3: And more words. Not really making sense.
4: Again the thing with the quick brown fox.

\begin{flushleft}
\specialsec{Something words}
\end{flushleft}

Here are some words to form some random text.
1: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
2: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
3: And more words. Not really making sense.
4: Again the thing with the quick brown fox.


\begin{flushleft}
\specialsec{Another thing}
\end{flushleft}

Here are some words to form some random text.
1: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
2: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
3: And more words. Not really making sense.
4: Again the thing with the quick brown fox.

\end{document}
```

Comment: You need `overlay`s at all the `\fill`s and `\draw`s since those path use the `curent page text area` node. But if all you want is a black rectangle and a line to the right below some text, you don't need `remember picture` or `current page text area` (you can use `\textwidth` to create the horizontal line). You don't even need TikZ just some `\rule`s and `\rlap`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need `overlay` when you're actually referencing `current page text area`, so add it to your `\fill`s and `\draw`s and you get:

[image]

However, you don't actually need `remember picture` and the `current page text area` node.

You know exactly where the left side of the text area is. That's there where you place your TikZ picture. Just put that what you want there to the left of your picture.

And you also know where the right side is, that's `\textwidth` farther to the right than the left side.

### Code

```
% !TeX spellcheck = en_Us

\documentclass[a4paper, DIV=15, german, fontsize=10pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newlength{\xdistance}
\setlength{\xdistance}{4pt}
\newlength{\yAbstand}
\setlength{\yAbstand}{10pt}
\tikzset{
  specialsec node/.style={
    inner sep=+0pt, inner ysep=+2pt, font=\LARGE\rmfamily,
    text=black, align=left, anchor=base},
  specialsec left/.style=black,
  specialsec line/.style=ultra thick}
\newcommand{\specialsec}[2][]{%
  \par\bigskip\noindent
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline, trim left=(sol), trim right=(eol),#1]
    \node[specialsec node] (AbschnittNode) {#2};
    \fill[specialsec left]([shift=(AbschnittNode.west)]0pt,\yAbstand)
      rectangle +(-\xdistance,-2\yAbstand) coordinate (sol);
    \draw[specialsec line] ([xshift=+\xdistance,yshift=+.5\pgflinewidth]sol)
      -- +(right:\textwidth) coordinate (eol);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  \par\bigskip}

\listfiles

\begin{document}
Here are some words to form some random text.
1: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
2: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
3: And more words. Not really making sense.
4: Again the thing with the quick brown fox.

\specialsec{Something words}

Here are some words to form some random text.
1: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
2: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
3: And more words. Not really making sense.
4: Again the thing with the quick brown fox.

\specialsec[specialsec line/.append style=green]{Another thing}

Here are some words to form some random text.
1: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
2: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
3: And more words. Not really making sense.
4: Again the thing with the quick brown fox.

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: If the node's content is wider than the text width, more work will be necessary but that will also extend to all elements of the picture.

Comment: This is one hell of an answer. TikZ-engineering to the max. :) Thank you, also for the additional notes. I think I understand the majority of it all. However, I do not fully understand the 2 arguments for the `\specialsec` definition. How come you use 2? And then put the first inside the tikzpicture options??? That I am unable to grasp, even with googling.

Comment: For that line with the `\textwidth`-bit, this is more exact: `(right:\textwidth-\xdistance)`. :)

Comment: The mandatory `#2` is the text bit, the optional `#1` can be used to adjust settings only for this instance of `\specialsec` like I did in the second example. And you're right, one needs to subtract `\xdistance` in the last path.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a `tcolorbox` for this kind of environment. I think it's easier than your proposal.

```
% !TeX spellcheck = en_Us
\documentclass[
a4paper,
DIV=15,
german,
%landscape,
%footheight=10pt,
fontsize=10pt,
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{myspecialsec}[1][]{%
sharp corners,
fontupper=\LARGE\rmfamily,
leftrule=4pt,
bottomrule=2pt,
toprule=0pt,
rightrule=0pt,
halign=left,
boxsep=1pt,
left=0pt,
bottom=0pt,
top=0pt,
colback=white,
#1
}

\listfiles

\begin{document}
Here are some words to form some random text.
1: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
2: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
3: And more words. Not really making sense.
4: Again the thing with the quick brown fox.

\begin{myspecialsec}
Something words
\end{myspecialsec}

Here are some words to form some random text.
1: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
2: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
3: And more words. Not really making sense.
4: Again the thing with the quick brown fox.

\begin{myspecialsec}[colframe=red!70!black]
Another thing
\end{myspecialsec}

Here are some words to form some random text.
1: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
2: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
3: And more words. Not really making sense.
4: Again the thing with the quick brown fox.

\end{document}
```

[image]